# lost my old grafana.db, is there anyway we can restore it?

Tags: grafana, graphite, collectd

lost my old grafana.db, is there anyway we can restore it ? The new grafana.db doesn't show my old dashboards. All my older dashboards have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the backup. If you don't have a backup then you're out of luck.